# Is workspace shared storage utilised by data that is placed by data flow in "Power BI managed data lake"?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When we create a data flow inside a power bi workspace, there are 2 options where the data flow data gets stored:

1. Power BI managed data lake
2. Bring your own azure data lake

In the 1st case, is the shared storage of the workspace impacted by the data that the dataflow puts into the power bi managed data lake? If not then what is the limit of the power bi managed data lake storage per workspace?